# Retry ansible ad-hoc when failure

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

In ansible playbook, we can detect the result of shell command, check then retry if having failure like this

```
---
# Retry when failure
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: www-data
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:

  - name: checking test task
    shell: bin/console ahihi
    args:
      chdir: /var/www/backend/current/
      executable: /bin/bash
    register: result
    until: result == 0
    retries: 3
    delay: 15
```

But **how can I config register/until/retries/delay in ansible ad-hoc command?** Because I need to run a small command (but sometimes failure during network issues or something like this) that need to retry at least 3 times before giving up.

Here is my ad-hoc command:

```
ansible -i cron -m shell \
                --become --become-user www-data \
                -a "/var/www/backend/current/bin/console ahihi"
```

Comment: There is no retry option in ad-hoc command. Workaround for this would be to write a shell script. In the script use the loop and call the ansible ad-hoc and capture the output in json format. if failed, re-run the command for n time and exit. Else exit the loop.

Comment: after taking time for working around, I confirmed there is no retry option in ad-hoc command (ansible 2.4.x) as @Sriram said. BTW, because I'm using Jenkins for calling ansible to run ad-hoc, so should be added retry logic on stage/step of jenkinsfile